# adding parameter from html form to jquery string

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, async-await, api-gateway

I am trying to add to the below async call in javascript which sends parameter `q=<query>`, the second parameter `l=<lquery>`, but I don't see it sent out, checked in dev tools console

```
var searchbox = $('input#search');
var langquery = $('input#fav_language');
var timer = 0;

// Executes the search function 250 milliseconds after user stops typing
searchbox.keyup(function () {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(search, 250);
});

async function search() {
  // Clear results before searching
  noresults.hide();
  resultdiv.empty();
  loadingdiv.show();
  // Get the query from the user 
  let query = searchbox.val();
  // Only run a query if the string contains at least three characters
  if (query.length > 2) {
    let lquery = langquery.val();   
    // Make the HTTP request with the query as a parameter and wait for the JSON results
    let response = await $.get(apigatewayendpoint, { q: query, l: lquery, size: 25 }, 'json');
```

the html body is below. i've tried referring to the radio form id an to the input name, both didn't worked

```
<body>
  <h1>InfoLang - Movie Plot At Your Language</h1>
        
  <form id="lang">
  <p>Please select language:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="it" name="fav_language" value="Italian">
  <label for="it">Italian</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="fr" name="fav_language" value="French">
  <label for="fr">French</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="he" name="fav_language" value="Hebrew">
  <label for="he">Hebrew</label>
  <br>  
  </form>
  
   
  <hr>
  <input id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search your movie" align="center">
```

Comment: This looks fine. What do you see in your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel?

Comment: *but i dont see that is sent out.* => The [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) is your friend... Under the network tab, check the request.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Is there an `<input id="fav_language">` element? Does it have a value entered when the AJAX call is made?

Comment: You could also `console.log({ q: query, l: lquery, size: 25 });` just above `let response...`

Comment: the dev console show only q=<value>, that why i am bit puzzled
the l param comes from radio button form on that page and langquery retrieve it initially to  lquery

i tried couple of options to fill out the langquery -used the id or name of the option in the radio button. none have filled the param
it seems to filling space in-xxxxxxx?q=matrix%20%20&size=25
added the form to the question above

Comment: console.log statement show-

{q: 'matrix', l: undefined, size: 25} 
l: undefined 
q: "matrix" 
size: 25 
[[Prototype]]: Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got this by-

```
if (query.length > 2) {
    let lquery
    if (document.getElementById('it').checked) lquery = 'it'
    if (document.getElementById('fr').checked) lquery = 'fr'
...
```

and for the display

```
let title = results[item]._source.title
        if (lquery == 'it') plot = results[item]._source.description_it
        if (lquery == 'fr') plot = results[item]._source.description_fr
```